# Empty array is getting printed above table while displaying table contents using ruby cgi

Tags: ruby

I want to display 2d array contents using ruby cgi. I am getting contents printed in the table format but getting empty array (["[\"\", \"\"]", "[\"\", \"\"]", "[\"\", \"\"]"]) printed above it. I have tried using 'each' method for iteraring over array but it is not working with cgi. Someone please suggest.

```
  @cgi.table {
     ar.map {|v|
        @cgi.tr{
            v.map {|l|
                @cgi.td {l}
              }
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What cgi are you mentioning?

Comment: I am using html4Tr cgi